# Syntax error when creating trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a new trigger in MySQL but no matter what I try I'm getting syntax error. I want to insert a value into the `html_id` column which would be a concatenation of letter `f` and column `id`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER htmlid 
BEFORE INSERT ON makelist_food
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.html_id IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id);
  END IF;
END
```

I also tried this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER htmlid 
BEFORE INSERT ON makelist_food
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.html_id IS NULL) THEN
  INSERT INTO makelist_food SET html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id);
  END IF;
END
```

And this (changing delimiter):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER htmlid 
BEFORE INSERT ON makelist_food
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.html_id IS NULL) THEN
  NEW.html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id);
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The error I'm getting: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id)' at line 6

I'm running MySQL 5.5.22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
delimiter |

    CREATE TRIGGER htmlid 
    BEFORE INSERT ON makelist_food
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF (NEW.html_id IS NULL) THEN
      INSERT INTO makelist_food SET html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id);
      END IF;
    END
    |
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! The only things you changed were that you changed the delimiter from $$ to | and typed delimiter keyword in lowercase. Is there any known issue with using $$ as delimiter?

Comment: I think the difference is the SET keyword

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference is the SET keyword. try this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER htmlid 
BEFORE INSERT ON makelist_food
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.html_id IS NULL) THEN
     SET NEW.html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id);
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```